# Celery not running new task

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I've readded an old Celery task to my Django app running on Heroku, but it's not being run by the worker. The task appears in the tasks when the worker starts, and I can see the scheduler sending it to the worker. However, it is never received by the worker. What can I do to troubleshoot this issue? Other tasks added are running fine and it runs fine on the staging server which is another instance on Heroku. I've tried restarting all the dynos and changing the name of the task and repushing it but that hasn't worked.

***Fixed with:

```
current_app.control.purge()
```

Answer (score 0):

***Fixed with:

current_app.control.purge()